# How to set up the TensorBoard in Iguazio to track my model training jobs?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to set up the Tensorboard to track my model training jobs in Iguazio, how can go about it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Iguazio UI, choose the `Services` tab
-> New Service -> TensorBoard -> Next Step -> for the Path, filling `/users/<name>/.tensorboard` -> Create Service -> Apply Changes.

You will have a Tensorboard service running. Run a TensorFlow training job and click on the Tensorboard link, you will be able to access the logs on the board like below:
[image]